# How to earn Crew Credit?

Tags: the-crew

In The Crew how do you go about acquiring Crew Credit? I have noticed it's another form of payment (instead of cash) which you can use to purchase upgrade or new vehicles, I just don't know how to get them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have used all the available CC (the ones that you get when you join a Faction), the only way to get more is to buy them for real money. Don't even care about those anyways; they are pretty much useless. Spend the existing ones on Perk points.